# how to competently and quickly "repack" lists?

Tags: r

example: introductory such

```
L1 <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(
    a = c(1,2,3),
    b = c(4,7,1),
    c = c(2,7,9)),
  df2 = data.frame(
    a = c(3,3,8),
    b = c(1,0,3),
    c = c(4,6,2)),
  df3 = data.frame(
    a = c(3,8,5),
    b = c(4,7,4),
    c = c(2,4,8))
)
ref <- data.frame(id = c("df1", "df2", "df3"))
type="char"
```

I tried binding lists and vectors, lists and list but nothing has result as I described in example
OUTPUT should be like:

```
super_list <- list(
   body1 = list( row = L1[["df1"]], ref = ref[1], type=type), 
   body2 = list( row = L1[["df2"]], ref = ref[2], type=type), 
   body3 = list( row = L1[["df3"]], ref = ref[3], type = type))
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about how should the final list look like or "repacked"?

Comment: I tried to turn your example into valid R code. If I got anything wrong, please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lapply` function takes a vector or list and returns a list based on applying a function to each element, so you could use this to achieve what you want.  I'm not completely clear on the output required, since the `ref[1]` part of the output in the question doesn't make sense, but I'm sure you can adapt the code below to your needs.

The code below applies a function to each element of `L1` (indexed by name because that's easier sometimes) and for each element returns a list with the dataframe, the name, and the type.  These are then combined into a super-list.

```
super_list <- lapply(names(L1),\(name) {
  list(row=L1[[name]],
       ref=name,
       type=ref[ref$id==name,"type"])
})

> super_list
[[1]]
[[1]]$row
  a b c
1 1 4 2
2 2 7 7
3 3 1 9

[[1]]$ref
[1] "df1"

[[1]]$type
[1] "char"


[[2]]
[[2]]$row
  a b c
1 3 1 4
2 3 0 6
3 8 3 2

[[2]]$ref
[1] "df2"

[[2]]$type
[1] "char"


[[3]]
[[3]]$row
  a b c
1 3 4 2
2 8 7 4
3 5 4 8

[[3]]$ref
[1] "df3"

[[3]]$type
[1] "char"
```